# Google play games quota - pricing and per app basis?

Tags: google-play-games

The google play api quota is 200K requests as per [this page](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/quotas). Assuming that his number is per app (and not per user of app), then is this not too less for any viable app?

I am implementing an app that has realtime multiplayer mode, for which I plan to use use google play games. Assuming that two players share there progress 10 times in a game, that would mean 20 API calls per game (I have ignored the api calls to set room, invite etc etc). Thus less 10K games can be played in a day. If every player plays 10 games a day, that comes to a support of only 1000 active users.

Is there something wrong in my understanding of the quota, or is google play services really so prohibited? Is there any other solution that would reduce my api calls.

Also whats the cost for more api calls? And is there any alternative solution for multiplayer games?

THanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing to the wrong API. The link you have provided is for the Google Play Developer API which is for subscription, in-app purchase and publishing. The API for sharing progress and other in-game API calls is the [Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/) which has a default quota of 50000000 requests/day and in which the user can have 500 requests per second(The quotas can be seen in the Developer's Console). You could also see [Managing Quota and Rate Limiting](https://developers.google.com/games/services/quota) for other info about the quota and limits.

Comment: If exceed the limit, do you know what the service price is?